# why is this.props.category returning undefined? Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

why is my this.props.category returning undefined both in the current version of the code, and also in the code that is commented out?
I followed a youtube video and did everything as instructed i don't understand what the issue might be.
Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import "./ProductListPage.css";
import { GET_PRODUCTS } from '../api/index.js'
import { Query } from 'react-apollo'
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {changeCategory} from "../state/actions/"

export class ProductListPage extends Component {
  
  render() {
    
   
    {console.log(state.category)}
    return (
      
      <div>{this.props.category}</div>
      
      // <Query query={GET_PRODUCTS}>
      //   {
      //     ({ data, previousData, loading, error }) => {
      //       if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>
      //       if (error) return <div>Error: {error}</div>   
      //       console.log(this.props.category)
      //       return (
      //       <>
      //       <div>{this.props.category}jj</div>
      //       </>
      //       )
      //     }
      //   } 
      // </Query>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   
   return { 
     category: state.category
     
    };
  
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    changeCategory
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProductListPage)
```

My state

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   
   return { 
     category: state.categoryReducer, // change here
    };
  
};
```

if it does not work, check the key of category reducer that has been register when combine all reducer and put to store

Comment: I did try that, it returned undefined as well. This is my combined reducer:                                                            
    import { combineReducers } from "redux";
    import { categoryReducer }  from "./category"

    export const allReducers = combineReducers (
    {
        categoryReducer
    }
    )

Comment: Please put your store here. Did you wrap the Provider and pass your store into Provider?